# Is this Newton binomial legal?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

is this equation proper?

$$
\binom {9} {12} = 0
$$

so if we have a binomial
$$
\binom {n} {k}
$$

and when
$$
n<k
$$
the result is 0?

Comment: You can define $\binom{n}{k}$ for nonnegative integer $n$ and integer $k$ with the convention that it equals $0$ if $k<0$ or $k>n$. Pascal stays valid. Sometimes that is indeed handsome.

Comment: How many 12-element subsets does a 9-element set have?

Comment: $f(x)=\binom{x}{12}$ is a twelfth degree polynomial. It has $12$ distinct roots, namely the integers $0,1,2,\dots,11$. In particular, yes, $f(9)=0$.

Comment: There is a general scheme even for complex numbers. There is a [nice lecture over here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html)

Comment: Yes.  And then we can state the binomial theorem as $(1+x)^9 = \sum\binom{9}{k} x^k$, where the sum is over all integers $k$.

Answer (score 3):

In general, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k\ge0$,
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}
$$
If $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k\gt n\ge0$, then the numerator has a factor of $0$.

As drhab mentions, if $k\lt0$, it is makes sense to define
$$
\binom{n}{k}=0
$$
which is often done to simplify the limits of sums.

Comment: Is there any objection to define it as $0$ if $k$ is negative? Quite handsome in for instance http://math.stackexchange.com/a/633183/75923. No bothering about where to end also where to begin.

Comment: @drhab: indeed. I have added some to my answer to incorporate this.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the concept of binomial coefficient can be extended to allow the upper index to be real (or even complex). (Ronald L. Graham, Donald E. Knuth, and Oren Patashnik. Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science, 2nd ed. Addison-Wesley, 1994, Chap. 5)

In this way we can define binomial coefficient by:
$$
\binom{r}{k} = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{r(r-1)(r-2)\dots(r-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\dots(1)} = \dfrac{r^{\underline{k}}}{k!}, \; k \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \\
0, \quad k<0.
\end{cases}
$$
Where $r\in \mathbb{R}$

That means we can compute:

$$
\binom{-1}{3}=\dfrac{(-1)(-2)(-3)}{3!}=-1
$$

Despite the fact there's no combinatorial interpretation here.

Also, as pointed by bof, we can also look into $\dbinom{r}{k}$ as a $k$th-degree polynomial in r.

I really recommend the book mentioned above if you want to understand more about binomial coefficients.

Edit:
Just to complement, in your example:
$$
\binom{9}{12}=\dfrac{9\cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdots \cdot 0 \cdot (-1) \cdot (-2)}{12!}=\dfrac{0}{12!}=0.
$$